# Cross platform application embedding Webkit with WebGL support

Tags: python, webkit, cross-platform, webgl, vala

I need to create a cross platform (Win, Mac and Linux) application embedding a WebKit browser with HTML5 and WebGL support.
So far I used Java/SWT way, however using webkit on windows is only partially possible (win32 only, safari 5 only) and has limited html5 support, no 3D at all.

In linux I successfully embedded webkit2gtk3 with WebGL support in vala like this:

```cs
using GLib;
using Gtk;
using WebKit;

public class Browser : Window {
    private const string URL = "http://lo-th.github.io/Oimo.js/index.html";

    public Browser() {
        this.add(this.create_web_window());

        this.destroy.connect(Gtk.main_quit);
    }

    private ScrolledWindow create_web_window() {
        var view = new WebView();
        view.get_settings().set_enable_webgl(true);
        view.load_uri(Browser.URL);

        var scrolled_window = new ScrolledWindow(null, null);
        scrolled_window.set_policy(PolicyType.AUTOMATIC, PolicyType.AUTOMATIC);
        scrolled_window.add(view);

        return scrolled_window;
    }

    public static int main(string[] args) {
        Gtk.init(ref args);

        var browser = new Browser();
        browser.resize(800,600);
        browser.show_all();

        Gtk.main();

        return 0;
    }
}
```

compiled with

```
valac --vapidir=. --pkg gtk+-3.0 --pkg webkit2gtk-3.0 --thread hellowebkit.vala
```

I also had success with python like this:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gtk, webkit

w = gtk.Window()
w.set_title("Example Editor")
w.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
w.resize(800,600)

scroll = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
w.add(scroll)

browser = webkit.WebView()
browser.get_settings().set_property("enable-webgl", True)
scroll.add(browser)

w.show_all()

browser.open("http://lo-th.github.io/Oimo.js/index.html");

gtk.main()
```

So the question now is: Is there any chance (and documentation) to get any of the above (compiling) and running in Win32/64 and OSX with WebGL support too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this could help

https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit

App runtime based on Chromium engine and node.js. Supports HTML5, CSS3, JS and WebGL.
Did try it for a simpler project without WebGL, worked smooth. Very easy to setup too.

Check this slideshare, might help in deciding whether it is relevant

https://speakerdeck.com/zcbenz/node-webkit-app-runtime-based-on-chromium-and-node-dot-js

**UPDATE:** Found a couple of more alternatives to do similar stuff, not tried yet

1. https://github.com/milani/appjs
2. https://www.tidekit.com/

Another stackoverflow thread which might help [Alternatives to node webkit? (filesize of importance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22254375/alternatives-to-node-webkit-filesize-of-importance)

Comment: I had a quick look and It seems very interesting. It's a bit differenti from what I had in mint (embedding WebKit in either java or py) bit It could ne a powerful alternative to achieve the same objectives. Thanks!

Comment: I just tested it and it works with webgl too (on arch linux). The unhappy side is that the project is still in demo/preview mode and you can see it from the segmentation errors that often appear. I side note for Arch Linux users: since arch linux is now using systemd, you have to create a symlink like this for libcef to work: ln -sf /usr/lib/libudev.so.1.0.1 /usr/lib/libudev.so.0

Comment: Oh ok, didn't know that. Tried on Windows and Mac, worked fine. Anyway I have updated my answer with a couple of other alternatives on the same lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your **Vala example** uses WebKit2Gtk3. Unfortunately, WebKit2Gtk3 has not been ported to Windows yet. [Citing Carlos Garcia Campos](https://www.mail-archive.com/webkit-gtk@lists.webkit.org/msg01735.html):

> It's always been in our TODO list but as very low priority task, mainly
>   due to the lack of windows knowledge, time and people interested. Any
>   contribution to add windows support to WebKit2GTK+ would be more than
>   welcome, of course.

Probably only solution is to hire a developer to work on this task :-(

---

I'm not sure which version of WebKitGtk is used in your **Python example**. WebKitGtk3 should work on Windows, WebKit2Gtk3 doesn't exist for Windows. However, I have no experience with running Python/GTK/WebKitGtk apps on Windows.